# Detección idioma texto de entrada con Python

Tags: python

Mi cuestion es que yo escribo el siguiente código no?:

```
from textblob import TextBlob

eb = TextBlob('Texto cualquiera en un idioma cualquiera')

print(eb.detect_language())
```

Pero el caso es que me arroja como respuesta un fallo enorme que se resume en:

```
HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

Por tanto, me gustaria me indicarais como podria yo detectar el idioma en el que esta introducido un texto sin que para ello implique picar demasiadas lineas de código.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Para lo que queres, necesitarias MUCHISIMAS lineas de codigo... igual, aca no contestamos preguntas asi.. contestamos preguntas con problemas concretos....

Answer (score 0):

Esa librería muy seguramente llama un servicio externo, le envía cada palabra y recibe la traducción. Muy seguramente, también, tiene una tasa máxima de peticiones por segundo / minuto, etc.

De hecho, mirando la [documentación oficial](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/_modules/textblob/blob.html), vemos que ese método usa la API de Google Translate y por ahí está la explicación a esas limitaciones (por [acá](https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas?hl=en) hay más info; puede tomar hasta 24h para que se limpie la historia y te reciban peticiones de nuevo). El método, además, ESTÁ DEPRECADO y no debería usarse.

Por qué no usas [GoogleTrans](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? Algo como:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator.detect('이 문장은 한글로 쓰여졌습니다.')
<Detected lang=ko confidence=0.27041003>
```